# generate check-boxes based on drop-down selection?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

In my project, I have a one-to-many relation (a Client has many contacts), Now, I am listing the clients in a Drop-down menu, What i want is, To have the Selected Client's Contacts rendered dynamically as check-boxes.

Here is (the part) of my _form.html.haml, and the jQuery part that sends the Ajax request:

```
  %h4 This meeting is made for :
  = f.input :client_id, collection:(Client.all)
  %br
  %hr     


  %h4 Assign Contacts:
  //HERE WHERE I REALLY WANT THE CHECKBOXES TO BE REDNERED DYNAMICALLY.
  = check_box_tag "contact_ids[]", c.id, @meeting.contacts.include?(c)
  = c.first_name
  %br


  :javascript
    $(document).ready(function (){
      $('#meeting_client_id').change(function(){
      var state = $('#meeting_client_id :selected').val();
      if(state !== "")
      {
        $.getJSON('/clients/client_contacts/' + state, function(data){
        console.log(data);
        })
      }
     return false;
     })
   });
```

and here is my Clients_controller action, that handles the request:

```
def client_contacts
  client = (params[:id])
  cou = Contact.where(client_id: client)
  @msg = { "success" => "true", "message" => "hello", "count" => cou}
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @msg }
  end
end
```

Now, in the console, I can see that the request is returning the count, and objects.

and hence I am really new to JS/jQuery , and fairly new to Rails, I really don't know how to take it from here.

Any tips/Articles/links/Helps or advice, is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only part you're missing is the creation of checkboxes, you can try something like this;

```
var output = $("some selector for an element containing the checkboxes");

$('#meeting_client_id').change(function(){
    var state = this.value;
    if(state !== "") {
        $.getJSON("/clients/client_contacts/" + state).done(function(data) {
            output.empty(); // clear the container
            // assuming data is an array of strings, modify as needed
            $.each(data, function () { 
                // for each array item in the result, create a checkbox
                $('<input type="checkbox" value="'+this+'">'+this+'</option>')
                    .appendTo(output); // append it to the container
            });
        });
    }
});
```

The important parts I used here is:

- `$.each()` for looping through arrays: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/
- `$("<html>")` syntax for creating a new element: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2
- `.appendTo()` for attaching to the DOM: http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Here is a demo where i'm just using a custom function to fake the ajax call.

http://jsfiddle.net/kK622/1/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$.getJSON('/clients/client_contacts/' + state, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    data.each(function(){
        var id = data.id;
        var name = data.firstName;
        //add to new div with id myDiv
        $('#myDiv').append('<input name='+ id +' type="checkbox" /> ' + name + '<br />');)
    });
});
```